# How to move navigation bar image?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I want to set the image on left side of the navigation bar. I referred some tutorial but most of them saying *use button image to move the image to left* . Is there any code to move the image to left as a imageview not as the button image?

Comment: Can you clarify your question.I am just getting you add image on left side of navigation bar .

Comment: Actually i want an image to be displayed in the left side of the navigation bar as an image view not a button view.

Comment: Ya You can do that dynamically.add the imageview on navigation bar

Comment: But i cant move that to left side.Is there any code to move to the left .If so kindly post that

Comment: u can add the imageview on bar statically, for how many screens you wanted to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by adding your imageview on navigation bar. see below code It's working fine for me

```
bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];    
    [bar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    barImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navImg.png"]];
    [bar addSubview:barImg];


    tick_img_lbl=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(86, 6,34, 33)];
    tick_img_lbl.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick-1.png"];
    [bar addSubview:tick_img_lbl];
    [tick_img_lbl release];
```

here **bar** is UINavigationBar. I add an image in navigation bar and then add a imageview in specified co ordinate. try with This and let me know if any clarification needed..